# Node script needs to return success/failure to Angular service that called it

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, promise

I'm trying to make a request to a node function that will write to a file, but I'm not sure the best way to get the success or failure back to angular. The setup looks like this:

```
//controller (in an ng-click handler)
writeFileRoute.writeFile(file)
  .then(function(response){
    console.log('success', response);
  }, function(error){
    console.log('error', error);
});


 //service
app.service('WriteFileService', function($http) {
  this.writeFile = function(data) {
    return $http.post('/writeFile', data)
      .then(function(response) {
        return {
          'success': response
        };
      }, function(response) {
        return {
          'error': response
        };
      });
  };
})

//server.js
app.post('/writeFile', function(req, res){
  components.writefile(req.body, function(err){
    //do something with error here?
});

//by this point I have become increasingly confused by what is going on
//node write script
var writefile = function(data, callback){
  //data = JSON.stringify(data).message;
  fs.writeFile('./testFile.txt', data.message, function(err){
    callback(err);
  });
};
module.exports = exports = writefile;
```

So the file is actually writing. I just don't know how to combine these separately working components into something that can notify angular of success or failure. I thought about using `q`, however I don't know if I should use angular `$q` or node `Q`. I would really like to use `Q` and/or `$q`, but I don't know which is the right solution or where to plug them in.

## Edit (3 Feb)

This is the code that I am currently working with:

Angular:

```
angular.module('test', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope, WriteService){
    $scope.testMessage = "test"
    $scope.writeTheFile = function(){
      WriteService.write()
      .then(function(err){
        if (err){
          console.log(err);
        }else{
          console.log('no error');
        }
      });
    }
  })
  .service('WriteService', function($http){
    this.write = function(){
      $http.get('./write/', function(response){
        return {'success': response};
      }, function(error){
        return {'error': error};
      });
    };
  });
```

Node write module

```
var writes = {
    nfcall: function(data){
    data = data.repeat(5);
    return Q.nfcall(fs.writeFile, dest, data);
  }
}
```

Node Server

```
app.get('/write/', function(req, res, next){
  var data = 'some text string ' + +new Date() + '\n';
  writeModule.nfcall(data)
  .then(function(response){
    return {'response': response};
  })
  .catch(function(err){
    return {'index.js error': err};
  });
});
```

Comment: The file is being written asynchronously but you are not being notified because the callback you are passing into `components.writefile` (which is actually the function you're passing as the second parameter of `app.post`) it's called ONLY when there's an error.

Comment: @charliebrownie I think I would prefer to use promises over callbacks if I'm honest.

Comment: Yeah, Promises is a good alternative to callbacks. I usually work with Promises. Then you should be using Q in your server. You are already using them in your front, as `$http` uses them (have a look, you are using `then` method)

Comment: There it is, I hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

Promises are a very good alternative to callbacks, and `Q` is an excellent Promise library to use on your `node.js` backend:

`var Q = require('q');`

Your server will look like something like this:

```
app.post('/writeFile', function(req, res, next) {
  components.writefile(req.body)
  .then(function() {
    // Success! 'Writefile' worked fine, just send some 200 OK response.
    res.send('OK');
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    // If 'Writefile' fails, this will be called!
    // Just pass the error to the Error Handling middleware
    next(err);
  });
});

var writefile = function(data){
  return Q.nfcall(fs.writefile, './testFile.txt', data.message);
};

module.exports = exports = writefile;
```

Note that [`nfcall()`](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#qnfcallfunc-args) method is used for calling Node.js-style functions and getting back a promise.

Your `components.writefile` now returns a Promise, and what you do in `app.post` could be two things (have a look at the [Promise Core Methods](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#core-promise-methods)):

1. Catching any errors if your promise is rejected (`catch` method is called)
2. Istead, if the promise was resolved, `then` method is called.

I don't see anything wrong on your fronted, in fact, it already uses Promises: note that `$http` returns a Promise (have a look at it's [Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)).

Comment: ` and Q is an excellent Promise library` - if you're using Q (vs a modern library like bluebird) you might as well just use native ES promises.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Can you show how you would do this with bluebird?

Comment: @charliebrownie So what I'm missing here is how to get the success back to angular. Can you show what that should look like in the service/controller? Thanks!

Comment: Also, any idea why @BenjaminGruenbaum reckons that `Q` and ES promises are inferior?

Comment: I've reread the last part of your post and totally missed the part about the front end. Sorry, very distracted at the minute I guess. If native `$http` uses promises, what would you use `$q` for?

Comment: You are still using Javascript on the frontend, which means it works asynchronously as well (as the backend does). You have it written at the docs: `A service that helps you run functions asynchronously, and use their return values (or exceptions) when they are done processing.`

Comment: That `$http` uses promises just means that **it's** methods also return a Promise.

Comment: Your front was not getting any response when writing that file succeeded simply because it was expecting to handle your server response, but you never sent it back. Your problem was on your server. Have a look at my code, see: `res.send('OK');` is what returns a response to the server, and that response is your `response` at your success function of the `$http` call...

Comment: @thomas so, do you get it?

Comment: @charliebrownie Not quite. Sorry I've just been able to come back to this after so long.  I can make it write the file still, but am not getting any success or error returned to angular. I have updated the answer with my new code. Could you take a look?

Comment: @charliebrownie Do you think you could take a look at this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In `app.post`, you must return something back to the client through `res`. Use `res.send(data or error)`

See: http://expressjs.com/en/api.html

This also mean you do not need a promise from the server to the client. The promise for `writeFileRoute` will be resolved with the `res` return.